# Cannot get xmlread with IO Octave package to work even with proper .jar files

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, octave, xerces

I am trying to get the Octave 5.1.0 + IO package xmlread() function to work. I have installed the IO package as well as the 2.12.0 version of Apache Xerces java libraries.  Octave Forge claims that all you need to do is to load the IO package during runtime (pkg load IO) and include javaaddpath entries for two .jar files:

```
javaaddpath('pathToFile/xercesImpl.jar');
javaaddpath('pathToFile/xml-apis.jar');
```

I have done this, but I still get the following error:

```
error: xmlread: no xercesImpl.jar and/or xml-apis.jar > v2.11.0 in javaclasspath
error: called from
    xmlread at line 72 column 7
```

I made sure to addpath the Xerces libary, but I get the same error no matter what. When  I invoke the xmlread without a file (xmlread()), it seems to confirm the existence of the .jar files:

```
xerces:
  - xercesImpl.jar OK
  - xml-apis.jar OK
  xerces version 2.9.1
```

The 2.9.1 might be the culprit (>2.11.0 needed?), but why does this get used when I point to more current versions?  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here https://wiki.octave.org/Cookbook#Load_XML_files for a generic solution not requiring xmlread (presumably this is what is implemented under the hood anyway). Note the point about java and absolute paths. Are you providing the path to the API as a relative path by any chance?

Comment: Hi Greg! What OS and OS version are you running? Offhand, sounds like you might have the old 2.9.1 Xerces JARs on your Octave javaclasspath ahead of the 2.12 JARs. In Java, whichever JAR that comes first on the classpath masks other JARs that have classes with the same name; there is no version resolution stuff going on.